# Suppose $K \in R $ is a compact set and for $ x \notin K$, show that $inf\{|x - k| : k \in K\} > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $K \in R $ is a compact set and for $ x \notin K$, I want to show that $inf\{|x - k| : k \in K\} > 0$.

As $\{|x - k| : k \in K\} $ is non-negative set, its infimum is at least 0. So I am trying to show the inequality by showing the infimum is not equal to $0$. Is it possible to do so? If not, is there other way to prove the question?

Comment: Do you mean $K \subset \Bbb R$ instead of $K \in R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the infimum is $0$ the there is sequence $(k_n)$ in $K$ such that $|x-k_n| \to 0$. By compactness there is a subsequence $(k_{n_i})$ converging to some point $k$ of $K$. Now show that $|x-k|=0$ which gives the contradiction $x=k \in K$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The function $f:K \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(k) = |x - k|$ is a continuous function over a compact set.